# vbscript Function syntax error

Tags: function, vbscript, syntax-error

I've lifted the following code from a thread here [DateDiff in days, hours and mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821530/date-difference-in-day-hour-minutes-format?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but I'm getting a syntax error on the first line of code and I can't work out why because it looks the same as other function syntax I've written that works fine.

```VBScript
Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2) 

        seconds = Abs(DateDiff("S",dt1, dt2)) 
        minutes = seconds \ 60 
        hours = minutes \ 60 
        minutes = minutes mod 60 
        seconds = seconds mod 60 

        if len(hours) = 1 then hours = "0" & hours 

        TimeSpan = hours & ":" & _ 
            RIGHT("00" & minutes, 2) & ":" & _ 
            RIGHT("00" & seconds, 2) 

End Function 

dt1 = ActiveRequest.Fields("CreationDate").Value
dt2 = ActiveRequest.Fields("1stcontactdatetime").Value
```

The error I receive is: "Error in control script at line 1: Syntax error (Microsoft VBScript compilation error): FuntionTimeSpan(dt1, dt2)"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, especially if it helps me not do it again!

Comment: What scripting host are you using?

Comment: @Bond
I have run the following
`code MsgBox(ScriptEngine)  
MsgBox(ScriptEngineBuildVersion)
MsgBox(ScriptEngineMajorVersion)
MsgBox(ScriptEngineMinorVersion)
code`
I received the following VBScript, 17280, 5, 8
I believe it works with Windows Scripting Host

Comment: OK, so you're using WSH? Is it a VBS file or a WSF? Is your code contained in a single file or are you using script components? The "Error in control script" is not something I've seen often.

Comment: I am writing the script inside of another program and it's objects can be address and manipulated by VBScript. As such I don't really get to see my script as you've described but I'm inclined to think it's WSH based on the behaviour.

Comment: It's just odd because it sounds like it's erroring on the function declaration itself. Are you sure the program you're writing your script within doesn't already define a function named `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @Bond
That was the conclusion I came to also, no I've run a search on the contents of all scripts and there isn't any other functions with the same name, I also renamed it to something completely different that there wouldn't be a duplicate of and the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a sub or define a return variable.

Though my vbscript engine doesn't mind your code.

You are probably using the msscript.ocx (MS Script Control), it runs vbscripts in an application. Probably a help file in system32 for it.

Timespan is a class in the .NET framework.

The final thing is if using an edit control box, as notepad is and dialogs do, you get character problems. Paste into wordpad (based on a richtext edit control) so you can check for formatting edit controls ignore.

In the error message VBScript thinks there is no space between function and the function name.